# How do I take advantage of a property of Active in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hi everyone i have a panel admin with ajax and I want to when click on the tag a and page was loaded, Change the background color active tag a

html

```
<a id="BtnS1">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th">Dasboard</span>
</a>
```

js

```
$("#BtnS1").click(function(){
   $("#main").load("page/Dashboard.php");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `active` class to the `a` element when is clicked:

```
$("#BtnS1").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass("active");
   $("#main").load("page/Dashboard.php");
});
```

And write some CSS for this class.

Is this what you need?

---

#### My recomendation:

By the way, I **highly recommend** that you change the way you are performing the menu. You should use `class` instead of `id` for this pourpuse. And maybe a `data` attribute inside your `a` elements to load the appropiate URL when you click on your menu items:

```
<a class="linkOfMenu" data-url="Dashboard.php">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
   Dashbord 
</a>

$(".linkOfMenu").click(function(){
   $(".linkOfMenu").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
   $("#main").load("page/" + $(this).data("url"));
});
```

In this way it is much more simple and powerful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a css class active_a
<style>
    .active_a{
       background: green;
    }
 </style>
```

Now add this class using jquery

```
     <a class="links" id="BtnS1">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
        Dashbord 
    </a>
    <script>
       $(".links").click(function(){
           $(".links").removeClass("active_a");
           $(this).addClass("active_a");
           $("#main").load("page/Dashboard.php");
       }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: You can set  common class for every  <a><a> tag then when click any any a tag remove this class from each a tag Using jquery removeClass